# Why does Emacs fill-paragraph corrupt this paragraph layout?

Tags: fill-paragraph, auto-fill-mode

To reproduce what appears to be a bug that I'm encountering, create a new buffer with Emacs 26.1 (Fundamental mode is fine), and paste the following text in:

```
Without message passing to worry about, there is little need to
make invoking subroutines, be they functions or procedures,
late-bound literally all the time.  For this reason, Ascetic
Programming also dispenses with the idea that everything must
be late-bound.
```

Highlight the whole paragraph, and type M-x increase-left-margin RET to indent the paragraph four spaces.

Then put point on the `W` of `Without`, and perform the following in sequence: C-x f 70 RET M-q

Here's what I see after performing the above:

```
    Without message passing to worry about, there is little need
    to make invoking subroutines, be they functions or procedures,
    late-bound literally all the time.  For this reason, Ascetic
        Programming also dispenses with the idea that everything
    must be late-bound.
```

There are two problems that I see:  (1) the paragraph is now indented 8 spaces instead of 4 (this also happens if I ensure point is in column 0 of the first line as well), and (2) Programming is indented way too far.

My goal is to get a nicely filled paragraph that happens to have a left margin of 4.  What am I missing?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I cannot replicate that.  Does this happen under `emacs -Q` ?

Comment: This is incredibly bizarre; I, too, am no longer able to replicate the problem, at least in isolation.  :(